# Is there better solution than string.split() to pick first two lines from text chunk in ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to display first two lines from a chunk of text and add three dots at the end.

**Expected Output:** "This is some text. Another text..."

```js
const string = "This is some text. Another text. Also third. Repeated text. Repeated text.Repeated text.Repeated text.Repeated text.Repeated text.Repeated text.Repeated text.Repeated text. ";

const pickTwoLinesFromParagraph = (string) => {
  const newStrníng = string.split(/[.\r]/g);
  const twoLines = [newStrníng[0], newStrníng[1]];
  const output = twoLines.join('. ').concat('...');
  return output;
}

console.log(pickTwoLinesFromParagraph(string))
```

The above solution is what I have. However, this doesn't seem to be optimized.

Comment: I only see one line in the string...? Do you mean line or text ending with`.`?

Comment: you can use string.slice()

Comment: Why can't you get text up to the second occurrence of the '.' (dot) and append '...'?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Correct. Text ending with `.`, that means picking two sentences and displaying with `...` in the end of the second sentence. However, `output` in my code is indeed one `string`.

Comment: You could get the index of the second `.` like this: `string.indexOf(".", string.indexOf(".")+1)` Then `slice` the string till that index and add `...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove everything after the second `.` or `\r`:

```
const output = string.replace(/^([^.\r]+[.\r][^.\r]+).*$/, "$1...");
```

Live Example:

```js
const string = "This is some text. Another text. Also third. Repeated text. Repeated text.Repeated text.Repeated text.Repeated text.Repeated text.Repeated text.Repeated text.Repeated text. ";

const pickTwoLinesFromParagraph = (string) => {
    const output = string.replace(/^([^.\r]+[.\r][^.\r]+).*$/, "$1...");
    return output;
}

console.log(pickTwoLinesFromParagraph(string))
```

Comment: *(Apologies for the first version, I was in `vim` land and otherwise just not thinking. If you don't see `$1...` in the replacement string above, hit refresh.)*

Comment: what does this `"$1..."` mean?

Comment: See MDN's documentation for [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) -- it's a placeholder for the first capture group. The expression captures everything up to but not including the second `.` or `\r`, so `$1...` becomes all of that followed by `...`.

Answer (score 0):

You could match none dots and a dot twice.

```js
const string = 'This is some text. Another text. Also third. Repeated text. Repeated text.Repeated text.Repeated text.Repeated text.Repeated text.Repeated text.Repeated text.Repeated text. ';

const pick2 = string => string.match(/[^.]*\.[^.]*\./) + '..';

console.log(pick2(string));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is fine. It can be shorter if you use [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) after `split()`.

```js
const string = "This is some text. Another text. Also third. Repeated text. Repeated text.Repeated text.Repeated text.Repeated text.Repeated text.Repeated text.Repeated text.Repeated text. ";

const pickTwoLinesFromParagraph = string => {
  const [first, second] = string.split(/[.\r]/g);
  return `${first}.${second}...`;
}

console.log(pickTwoLinesFromParagraph(string))
```